# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response is undefined using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am trying to make a POST request and print the response. My code:

```js
async function create_invite(){
    console.log("creating.....")
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8080/webhooks', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    console.log(response.json())
}

document.getElementById('create_invite').addEventListener("click", create_invite)
```

But I getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response is undefined
```

I tried adding cors in the header but still doesnt work

Comment: you must be hitting the `.catch`  which returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix `await` with `.then` and `.catch`, it's easy to get confused. Your `await` is applying to the promise from `.catch`, **not** the promise from `fetch`. It looks like the `fetch` is failing, triggering the `catch`, which converts rejection into fulfillment with `undefined`. You'll need to look at why the `fetch` is failing, but it's still important to update the code.

There are a couple of other issues as well: before calling `response.json`, be sure to check whether the HTTP operation succeeded (`fetch` only rejects on *network* errors, not HTTP errors; an API footgun). Also, your code was trying to `console.log` the result of `response.json` directly, which is a promise; instead, `await` it so you see the data once it's been read and parsed.

Putting that all together:

```
async function create_invite() {
    console.log("creating.....")
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8080/webhooks', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**But**, I strongly encourage you **not** to catch errors there unless that's the top-level entry point (an event handler, etc.). Better to let them propagate to the caller (until the top-level entry point).

Comment: in Chrome, nothings gets printed in the console. The very first log "creating....." shows up for a second then disappears.

Comment: I changed the code, now Im getting TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: @Efaz - That's consistent with your original issue, because that would have gone to the `catch` and been converted to fulfillment with `undefined`. It's telling you that your browser can't reach `https://localhost:8080`. So you need to look at why that is. (For instance, is your server really running on port 8080? Is it really doing SSL? Is there an issue with the certificate?)

Comment: the server is working fine and the POST request is also working. I can see the change created by the POST request, but for some reason I am not getting the response properly. I tried Postman and made the same request and it worked.

Comment: @Efaz - Did you look in the browser console / network tab? Sounds like you're hitting the Same Origin Policy. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i).